# Emscript only change .wasm and .js file after recompile

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I worked through the tutorial [compiling from C/C++ to WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm). Under point "Calling a custom function defined in C" I have to edit the .html output after compiling.

How to avoid `emcc` from override the .html output if I would recompile .cpp?

The cause of avoiding to override .html output is, that I don't want to edit the html after recompiling. Because I think the glue code doesn't change if I only edit inside `myFunction`.

```
void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE myFunction(int argc, char ** argv) {
  printf("MyFunction Called Edits\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the .html file in the html_template folder rather than editing the .html output file. This should allow you to change your .c, .cpp or .html files and not lose the .html changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`--shell-file`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-shell-file) option, and pass in a path to a custom shell HTML file.

You can copy [the shell template](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/shell.html) from the Emscripten repository. Any code injected by emcc will be placed in the `{{{ SCRIPT }}}` token.